# Basic SUMIFS formula - adding an IF BUY/SELL to swap cash direction

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm making a template with the intention it provides the net sum of all settling FX values by currency and per a specified account/fund code and settlement date.

The formula below & in picture work however only if I'm concerned with FX buys settling on the day, as column F 'Currency Amount' values are absolute.

I'm not sure how to add something that also checks whether the column B value for that FX is a "SELL". If it's a cell, I need the column F 'Currency A'mount flipped (to indicate the value reduces the net sum figure).

[image: Screenshot of input data, formula and output]

`=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$590, $E$2:$E$590, U16, $J$2:$J$590, $U$14, $D$2:$D$590, $V$14)`

Comment: do two sumifs, the first to sum the Buy and the second to do the sell and subtract the second from the first.

Answer (score 0):

The value for "BUY" state, please try the formula below.

`=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$590,$B$2:$B$590,"BUY",$E$2:$E$590, U15, $J$2:$J$590, $U$14, $D$2:$D$590, $V$14)`

The value for "SELL" state, please try the formula below.

`=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$590,$B$2:$B$590,"SELL",$E$2:$E$590, U15, $J$2:$J$590, $U$14, $D$2:$D$590, $V$14)`

Then you could combine the two formulas with a "minus sign".

`=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$590,$B$2:$B$590,"BUY",$E$2:$E$590, U15, $J$2:$J$590, $U$14, $D$2:$D$590, $V$14)-SUMIFS($F$2:$F$590,$B$2:$B$590,"SELL",$E$2:$E$590, U15, $J$2:$J$590, $U$14, $D$2:$D$590, $V$14)`